# Несовпадение координат тачскрина и transform.position

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
Transform tr;
void Start () 
{
    tr = transform;
}
void Update () {
if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        foreach(var th in Input.touches)
        {
            tr.position = new Vector3(th.position.x, th.position.y, 0); ;
        }
    }
}
```

Задача простая - надо чтобы следовал за пальцем объект. 
  Код висит на этом объекте.
  Проблема в следующем - при разных разрешениях экрана код работает по разному! 
  Даже банальный переворот экрана смещает объект на 200 пикселей влево и вверх, т.е. он следует не за пальцем а за точкой, которая выше и левее пальца. При разрешении экрана та же история. 
  Камера Ortho,  левый нижний угол камеры на координатах 0,0,0.
 В чем дело, понять не могу. Есть простая замена данному коду, чтобы объект просто повторял координаты пальца, пиксель к пикселю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего нужно конвертировать координаты нажатия в координаты точке в игре.

Можно попробовать воспользоваться [Camera.ScreenPointToRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html) - возвращает луч, идущий от камеры через точку на экране.

Т.е. например у нас есть одно нажатие

```
var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
```

Конвертируем его

```
var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch);
```

Позиция будет храниться в *origin*, т.е. `ray.origin.x` и `ray.origin.y`

Т.е. по факту `transform.position = ray.origin;` т.к. и transform.position и ray.origin это Vector3

т.е. будет что-то типа такого:

```
foreach(var th in Input.touches)
{
    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(th);
    tr.position = new Vector3(ray.origin.x, ray.origin.y, 0); // tr.position = ray.origin;
}
```

---

Если не получится *ScreenPointToRay*, то можно попытать счастье с [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html). Там уже не будет *origin*, метод преобразует position (позицию) из экранного пространства в мировое пространство и сразу возвращает Vector3.

Comment: Спасибо! 
Пара вопросов!
А можно как то проделать это с пикселями, без конвертации? Нет ли каких нибудь настроек камеры в Unity, при которых всегда были бы координаты тачскрина равносильны координатам на экране? 

Если делать через Ray, то не будет ли это более требовательно к ресурсам?

Comment: @Dmitrii я не знаю. мне кажется ScreenPointToRay центрирует координату, ведь плоскость нажатия большая. Ray часто применяют в 2в платформерах для определения расстояния до предмета. Причем делают это так, что из каждой стороны выпускаются  от 3 до 10 лучей для точности. Так что если не планируется, что будет нажато одновременно десятков пальцев, а 1,2,3 - то вполне.